# What is dilution percentage called?

Tags: terminology, percentages

So I am trying to find out what the following method is called, that is used to calculate a dilution.

Soap makers would mix their main ingredient with a base product which dilutes the main ingredient. They would say something like "dilution 25%". This means that they would take 100ml of the base product and add 25ml of the main ingredient.

However, I would say the whole 125ml so the dilution is 31.25% or 68.75% percent depending on which way you are looking at it.

I think maybe dilution is the wrong word to be using, however does this have a name or logic?

Comment: I could understand if you wanted to say $20\%$ (of the final $125\mathrm{ml}$, the main ingredient content of $25\mathrm{ml}$ makes up $20\%$), but how do you figure $31.25\%$? Where did that number come from?

Comment: You are correct, my error.

Comment: This question belongs better on [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, as per my comment above, that you really meant $20\%$, not $31.25\%$, then I understand your confusion. However, there is a good reason you would do it the way they do it: It's practical when you're actually making it.

Consider this: Say you make soap batches of many different sizes, but they all have the same proportions of ingredients: $20\%$ of the finished product is main ingredient, $80\%$ is base ingredient.

When you're writing a recipe, and especially if you're teaching assistants to help you, which would you find less confusing and prone to error? Which one is easiest to do quickly, in the head, on the fly, as you go about your daily routine in the soap factory?

- First take the base ingredient, then add main ingredient until $20\%$ of the mix is main ingredient
- First take the base ingredient, then add main ingredient corresponding to $25\%$ of the amount of base ingredient

Comment: Thanks, so do you think dilution is the correct word when referring the the amount you are increasing the whole by?

Comment: I think it sounds ambiguous if you're not used to it. I would personally prefer if it was called "dilute 1:4", or even written out in words "dilute 1 part to 4 parts base". But conventions are often made for brevity, and if that's what is generaly used, then you will just have to get used to it, I think.